# apt-get build-dep command fails for pantheon-mail fails

Tags: pantheon

I'm trying to build pantheon-mail again and having problems installing the build dependencies using this command

`$ sudo apt-get build-dep pantheon-mail
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for pantheon-mail`

deb-src entries in sources.list

`$ sudo grep "deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/" /etc/apt/sources.list
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse`

Comment: who is are the friggen' toolboxes that voted this question down and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add a repository from *elementary OS team* in order to download the source package for pantheon-mail.  Try:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
```

Open Software and Updates and look for new repository added. Mark line for sources an close. When it ask you to update source.list, accept it.

Warning:

> Beware of upgrade or dist-upgrade meanwhile you make build-dep.

When you have finished:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
```

To remove the repository.